# DNS simplification for interal AD domain resources

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

Best practice dictates to use something like "ad.domain.com" instead of "domain.com" for internal AD domain. I am setting up a new site and I have just one apprehension left before I follow this advice...

I really want to follow this, expecially since we have an outwardly facing "domain.com" website, but I'm curious how to handle ease of use.

I have created a UPN so that users can sign in and use "user@domain.com" instead of "user.ad.domain.com" to make it easier...

But when resolving internal machines and resources, I don't want to have to deal with "PC1.ad.domain.com" all the time. What is the best practice or workaround to be able to resolve this as simply PC1.domain.com? I realise this is something minute, and won't really apply to clients as I can just resolve "PC1", but for internal applications and servers, I don't want to have to have end users and others to deal with "appserver.ad.domain.com", it doesn't feel "correct" :)

Thanks!

Comment: One purpose of using a different domain for your internal AD is to differentiate between devices. Rather it feels correct or not, it is. If you want to use domain.com to resolve everything than use it for your internal AD and run split-DNS.

Comment: I guess the "ad" part of the "ad.domain.com" part is making it "weird", I assume using something like "server1.internal.domain.com" would relieve the issue and make it clear that it is an internal resource and not external, but I haven't seen anyone ask this question or found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You're inventing a problem that doesn't exist.

All domain joined machines will use the domain DNS Suffix as their primary DNS Suffix. Users, applications, and servers don't have to "deal" with this. They don't have to do anything. They'll use the primary DNS Suffix in name registration and name resolution. For non-domain joined machines you can simply configure them with the domain DNS Suffix for use with name registration and name resolution.

Using ad.domain.com (or something to that effect) is correct, whether it feels that way to you or not.

Comment: I understand I'm nitpicking, but I'm not sure what you mean by "They don't have to deal with this" There is a difference between resolving server1.domain.com and server1.ad.domain.com...one resolves and one does not, how do I overcome that?

Comment: You're thinking that you have to do something special to resolve server1.ad.domain.com, and you don't. DNS name resolution in AD works the same regardless of the DNS Suffix. As I stated, domain joined machines will use the domain DNS Suffix as their primary DNS Suffix for name registration and resolution. Non-domain joined machines can be configured to do the same. I'm not understanding what you're envisioning as potential problems. Maybe you can clarify with some specific use cases or scenarios.

Comment: Thank you for sticking it out, I guess this is only "weird" for me as I have only seen "splitbrain" DNS set-ups in the past and would like to set this site up correctly. simply put, doing a Ping on PC1.domain.com will not work in a best practice environment (I am aware resolving "PC1" alone will work) furthermore, spinning up IIS and hosting "webapp.ad.domain.com" will be a departure for the users that may be used to "webapp.domain.com". but before going any furthur, is there an actual way to achieve (via DNS) the result im looking for, and secondly why or why not?